# Styling HTML5 Datalist

Tags: html, datalist

So, I have `HTML5 datalist`however I can't seem to be able to style it.

Other articles seemed to be outdated and could not find much information about styling datalist.

I have over 100 options and the options go over the screen, so datalist without being able to style is bit useless.

In this case, what other options do you recommend that do similar functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33526739/21655. It essentially hooks into the existing select and lets you filter it yourself.